# Is using dd to read from /dev/ttyUSB0 the best option?

Tags: bash, dd

I'm having some issue with the use of `dd` to get the content coming from `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The idea is to poll a device every 5 min (for testing). I will probably use a cron job later but for now, I'm checking every minute and polling every 5.

My issue occurs at the `dd` line. Sometimes, it gets stuck there. I tried using `read -r line` but that's the same thing. My guess is that there is nothing to read.
- How can I prevent `dd` or `read` to stop if there is nothing coming from `/dev/ttyUSB0`?
- Or/and is there a better alternative to return the content of `/dev/ttyUSB0`?

Here's my code, simplified:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
  curdate=`date "+%M"`
  if [[ "$curdate %5" -eq 0 ]]; then

    echo Letspoll
    echo Polldata > /dev/ttyUSB0

    line=`dd if=/dev/ttyUSB0 count=1 2>/dev/null`
    #read -r line < /dev/ttyUSB0

    if [ !"$line" ]; then
      echo $line
    else
      echo Nothing
    fi

  fi

  echo Sleepingfor60sec
  sleep 60
done
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `count` parameter to `dd` specifies a number of *bytes*, not *lines*, to read. I'll assume you want to a line, in which case `dd` is the wrong tool to use.

```
# Exit with status 1 if nothing read in 5 seconds
if read -r -t 5 line < /dev/ttyUSB0; then
     echo "$line"
else
     echo Nothing
fi
```

Also, there's no reason to use `date` for sleeping between polling events; just `sleep 300` after each attempted `read`.

Comment: Thanks chepner. That's much better. I'm still using `date` because later, I will want to poll the data every 15 minutes, at "round" time (like 1:15, 1:30, ... and not 1:20, 1:35, ...).